# Lost network after installing connman

Tags: network-manager, internet, connman

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, I wanted to try `connman` so I ran:

```
Apt-get install connman
```

After it finished I lost my internet. I restarted the computer and I no longer have the network icon in the top right.

I tried uninstalling `connman` and restarting with no success.

I also tried restarting network manager.

```
Service network-manager stop
Service network-manager start
```

When I open the network settings application I get "The system network services are not compatible with this version".

Comment: This might help to someone. I’ve had to on/off WiFi rfswitch on my Lenovo laptop. I could ifconfig up my card again

Answer (score 3):

First I had to reconnect to the internet using the following steps:

1. List all network devices with `ifconfig -a` (in my case it was `wlo1`)
2. Turn device on `sudo ifconfig wlo1 up`
3. Manually use device to scan wifi `sudo iwlist wlo1 scanning` saw my wifi `Prk`
4. Associate device with wifi `sudo iwconfig wlo1 essid Prk`
5. Give device an IP `sudo dhclient wlo1`

Then I reinstalled `network-manager` which seemed to revert the broken settings:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment: This happens for me  also and it fixed exactly in the same manner

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Philip Kirkbride didn't work for me. It appears my device had become blocked with RFkill. I'm running Ubuntu 19.04. Here are the modified steps I followed:

1. List all network devices with `ifconfig -a`, look for wireless interface. In my case it was `wlp3s0`.
2. Attempt to turn device on `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up`. This returned an error message related to RFKill.
3. List rfkill info with `rfkill list all`, this shows that the "Wireless LAN" device was indeed marked with

```
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

4. Unblock all devices with `rfkill unblock all`
   5 Running `rfkill list all` now shows Wireless LAN device changed to unblocked
5. Reboot and the issue was resolved

Note, I attempted to follow steps 3, 4 and 5 in the answer by Philip after `rfkill unblock all`, but these produced errors in my case.